# getID from named sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get the ID (string) from a named sheet? I am trying to apply a filter to a named sheet. All the examples I have seen is to get the id from the active sheet. But I want to use it for a named sheet. How do I do it?

```
var resultSheet = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Result");
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': request}, resultSheet.getSheetId());
```

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName().getSheetId(()`[Reference:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: Sorry I think my question is not clear. The call to "Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate" expects sheet ID as string. This "string sheet ID" can be obtained by the call "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()". The call to "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getsheetID()" returns an integer value. I would like get a "string sheet ID" without using the 'active sheet' call. Is there a way to do it? Or should I first activate the sheet and then make this call? The reason is that I want to avoid unnecessary switches between sheets by activating multiple sheets.

Comment: Do you want a `sheetId`? Or a `spreadsheetId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relevant "ID" types for Google Sheets - one corresponds to the currently-open Google Sheets file - the [`spreadsheetId`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id) which is also the exact same value as the Google Drive `fileId` - and the other corresponds to a specific [`Sheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) within the Google Sheets spreadsheet, and is interchangeably known as a [`gridId` or `sheetId`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id).

From a given `Sheet` object, you can use the class method [`getParent()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getparent) to obtain a reference to the enclosing `Spreadsheet` object. A [`Spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) has the method [`getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid) which will return the needed `fileId`/`spreadsheetId` for the Sheets API [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) method.

It is very common to already have a reference to the spreadsheet:

```
const wkbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sheet = wkbk.getSheetByName("some name");
// ...
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': request}, wkbk.getId());
```

Depending on how your code is structured this reference may be out of scope, and perhaps you don't want to / can't include the relevant ID in the function's argument list:

```
function foo() {
  const wkbk = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const wkbkId = wkbk.getId();
  // ...
  doSheetUpdate_(wkbk.getSheetByName("some name"));
  // ...
}
function doSheetUpdate_(sheet) {
  const wkbkId = sheet.getParent().getId();
  const rq = getRequest_(sheet.getSheetId());
  // ...
  const resp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': rq}, wkbkId);
}
function getRequest_(sheetId) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`var sheetID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Your sheet name").getSheetId();`

sheetID will contain a string with the sheet's ID

See the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetid

Comment: Sorry I think my question is not clear. The call to "Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate" expects sheet ID as string. This "string sheet ID" can be obtained by the call "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()". The call to "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data").getsheetID()" returns an integer value. I would like get a "string sheet ID" without using the 'active sheet' call. Is there a way to do it? Or should I first activate the sheet and then make this call? The reason is that I want to avoid unnecessary switches between sheets by activating multiple sheets.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it did return a string. In that case simply add .toSring()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the post, I got the answer I was looking for. Here is the code that I can use.

```
var resultSheet = spreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Result");
var myID = resultSheet.getParent().getID();
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': request}, myID);
```

This will help me to avoid sheet switching.